# What is the proper way to implement OAuth2 Client and AuthServer in Spring Cloud (Microservice Architecture)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I was learning Microservice architecture from `Spring Microservices In Action` book.

As one of things I wanted to migrate examples which were built on `Spring Boot 1.4.4` and `Spring Cloud Camden.SR5` to `Spring Boot 2.1.6` and `Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR1`.

Now, I'm having problems with migrating of OAuth2 Auth server and resource servers since Spring decided to change packages/placement of classes and I feel completly lost since nothing seems to work.

Documentation seems to be splitted into `SpringBoot/SpringSecurity/SpringOAuth2` depedencies.

What is the proper way of implementing OAuth2 AuthServer and ResourceServer in current (2.1.6) version of SpringBoot with `Spring cloud Greenwich`?

Comment: I have some example here, if it helps you:
https://github.com/zlaval/advanced-spring-microservices

I will improve the md  on the weekend. If you want to try, the docker branch can build the whole project and run it.

Comment: FYI, please see this announcement https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security

Comment: Here is an example using the new Client and Resource Server features in Spring Security 5.1 https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-protocol-patterns. You will also see links to reference documentation in the README of the repo. NOTE: Authorization Server support is targeted for 5.3 release mid 2020.